# Pthread Best way to wake a number of threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, conditional-statements, mutex

I would like to know what's the best way to wake up a number of threads at once with a loop
I thinked about using a pthread_cond but I don't need a mutex since I'm not waiting for a ressources

Theres's n threads with :

```
start of thread
loop
action
wait
end of loop
```

And then the main thread wwill notice them all to start working.
Is it better to use a pthread cond with a mutex per thread or is it better to recreate the threads each time the task is finished ?

Comment: Creating threads only once should be better options as thread creation and cleanup may impact overall performance if its done frequently

Comment: @Pras So for this solution I need to create a mutex for each threads which will be only for the conditions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use a condition variable for this.  The way it works is that your condition is over some shared variable that the main thread sets to indicate that the worker threads should continue.  You do require a mutex because you *do* have a shared resource - the shared variable that the main thread sets and the worker threads read.

Something like:

```
/* shared variables */
int run_iteration = -1;
pthread_mutex_t iteration_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t iteration_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

Worker threads:

```
int current_iteration = 0;

while (... )
{
    /* Wait for main to signal start of current_iteration */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&iteration_lock);
    while (run_iteration < current_iteration)
        pthread_cond_wait(&iteration_cond, &iteration_lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&iteration_lock);

    /* ... Execute current_iteration ... */

    current_iteration++;
}
```

Main thread:

```
/* signal start of next iteration */
pthread_mutex_lock(&iteration_lock);
run_iteration++;
pthread_cond_broadcast(&iteration_cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&iteration_lock);
```

Alternatively, if you need your threads to run in lockstep then a pthread barrier (`pthread_barrier_t`) could be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the use of the variable, I searched that I could use a sem_t to do the same thing too.